# checkboxes and textfields jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, button, checkbox, textfield

I have 5 checkboxes in class check(named cb1, cb2, cb3, ...) and 5 corresponding textfields in class text(named tf1, tf2, tf3, ...). When one or more checkboxes are checked I want to count all checked checkboxes and place the sum into the textfields that correspond when a button is clicked.

Example: If cb1 and cb3 are checked than tf1 and tf3 will have value 2.

So far I am counting total checked checkboxes like so:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    total= $('.check:checked');
    count=total.length;
});
```

But I can't figure out how to get 'count' in the corresponding textfields. Any help is appreciated!

P.S. I have different checkboxes and textfields in different classes so it is important they are referenced by class.

Comment: 'Twould be easier to answer if you could show the relevant html...

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: declare your variables with var. ie `var total = ...` otherwise they become global

Comment: Raminson: I didn't even know what a jsfiddle was till I saw one in the answer below but it is cool and I will use it in the future but he nailed it so it seems unnecessary now, good looking out though! +1 for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a little something like this:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    var total= $('.check:checked'),
        count=total.length;

    $('.text').val(function() {
       return $('#' + this.id.replace(/tf/,'cb')).is(':checked') ? count : 0;
    });
});
```

Each element with class `text` will be updated to have a value of either `count` or `0` depending on whether its corresponding checkbox is checked. Obviously if you'd prefer you can blank out the fields corresponding to unchecked checkboxes by replacing `0` with `''` (empty string).

(For more information on passing a function to the [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/), read [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/val/).)

Note that you should always declare your variables with `var` or you create globals.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aBSNy/

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to give you code that wouldn't require any changes at all to your existing html. (Note also that my code clears the values out of the text fields where a corresponding checkbox was previously checked but isn't any more - something that the other answers don't do...)

Comment: Woah, good looking out on clearing the value out! I didn't even realize I needed that until you mentioned it! And props on the note about creating globals, I did not know that! I'm so impressed by these answers because I've learned a little something new from everyone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="" data-count-for="check1" />
</div>
...(other checkboxes)...
<div>
    <input id="trigger" name="trigger" type="button" value="Click me" />
</div>​
```

JavaScript (using jQuery 1.7+):

```
jQuery("#trigger").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // select checkboxes:
    var checkboxes = jQuery(':checkbox:checked');
    checkboxes.each(function(){
        // find text input assigned to each checked checkbox:
        var selector = '[data-count-for="' + jQuery(this).attr('name') + '"]';
        // assign it a total number of previously found checkboxes
        jQuery(selector).val(checkboxes.length);
    });
});​
```

See proof here: http://jsfiddle.net/EMhuw/1/

Comment: I didn't know what jsfiddle was before you! Super thanks you nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the textarea and the corresponding checkboxes have id's and name's that match, so you can easily bind them together, and then loop through the collection of checked checkboxes and use the `name` attribute from the checkbox as the `id` for the textarea, like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
// your already-computed total
count = total.length;

// loop through the collection of checked checkboxes
$('.check:checked').each( function() {

    // assign the total to each textarea where the id matches a checkbox name attr
    $('#'+$(this).attr("name")).val(total);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check1" />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check2" />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check3" />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check4" />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check5" />

<textarea id="check1"></textarea>
<textarea id="check2"></textarea>
<textarea id="check3"></textarea>
<textarea id="check4"></textarea>
<textarea id="check5"></textarea>
```

Using matching, enumerated ids/names, you'll also find it's easier to generate more checkboxes and textareas on the server-side, using a looping construct; thus, this can scale to much more than just 5 elements.

Comment: Great answer! I wish I could accept all the answers! Thank you for your help, much appreciated!